# preg_match and a troublesome regex

Tags: php, regex

Could some one tell me why

```
//string
$content = 'random ${one.var} ${two.var} random';

//match
preg_match('/(?:(?<=\$\{))([\w.]+){1}(?=\})/i', $content, $matches);
```

is returning

```
print_R($matches);

//output
array(
   [0]=>one.var
   [1]=>one.var
);
```

What i want is

```
array(
   [0]=>one.var
   [1]=>two.var
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the whole regex (0) as the inner capture `()` (1) match the same thing, so that part of the match makes sense. You probably want `preg_match_all`, which captures all matches...

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\$\{)[\w.]+(?=\})/i', $content, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `preg_match_all` to perform a global regex search, also - i think you can simplify the pattern this way:

```
preg_match_all('/\$\{(.*?)\}/', $content, $matches)
```

Comment: Thanks. But i dont need the '${' and '}' bits. reasons for the look arounds. Never knew i needed the preg_match_all in lieu of the /g modifier. Thanks. Now tho with `(?:(?<=\$\{))(.*?)(?=\})` its returning `array( array(
   [0]=>one.var
   [1]=>two.var
),array(
   [0]=>one.var
   [1]=>two.var
))`

Answer (score 0):

just try preg_match_all()

> http://php.net/preg_match_all Searches subject for all matches
>
> http://php.net/preg_match Searches subject for a match